# Is this the correct way to access a column through a pointer?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a pointer to the user class and I am trying to access the phone number. The name of the column inside the user class is "phone". Is this the correct way to access the value?

```
query.include("User");
query.each(function(test) {
  var usernum = test.get('User.phone');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat test.get('User') as a _User, and then using user.get('phone')

```
query.include("User");
query.each(function(test) {
  var user = test.get('User');
  if(user) console.log(user.get('phone'));
});
```